# Timer in For Loop, Counter not Incrementing?

Tags: c#, .net, timer, windows-forms-designer

For context, what I'm trying to do here is when the form loads, an array of timers with different intervals are created. Each timer is associated to form labels which will show once the timer elapsed.

I tried the code below just to check if the counter (timerCtr) is incrementing using a messagebox. Ten messageboxes pops up at the correct intervals, but shows the value 10 on all messageboxes.

Tried creating a breakpoint at a for loop and stepped into each line of code. The timerCtr is incrementing correctly, starting from 0 to 10, but the messageboxes showed different values.

What's causing this? Been looking for hours, but still can't figure it out.

```
Control[] finalLabelArray = new Control[10];

for (int ctr = 1; ctr < 11; ctr++)
{
    finalLabelArray[ctr] = this.Controls["key" + (ctr).ToString()];
}

System.Timers.Timer[] timerArray = new System.Timers.Timer[finalLabelArray.Length];

for (int timerCtr = 0; timerCtr < timerArray.Length; timerCtr++)
{
    timerArray[timerCtr] = new System.Timers.Timer(timerCtr * 1000 + 1000);
    timerArray[timerCtr].Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show(timerCtr.ToString());
        string labelString = finalLabelArray[timerCtr].Name.ToString();
        int lengthSubstring = labelString.Length - 3;
        int labelNumber = int.Parse(labelString.Substring(3, lengthSubstring));

    };
    timerArray[timerCtr].AutoReset = false;
    timerArray[timerCtr].Start();
}
```

Also, is there a better way to implement this instead of using a timer?

Thank you.

Comment: @XiangWeiHuang I just noticed it now and it showed null. I feel like this is related to the anonymous function that I used but can't pinpoint exactly how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `timerCtr.ToString()` is calculated upon `Elapsed` is called - `timerCtr` thus *lives* even after for loop ended, where it tops at 10. You can change the max value of `timerCtr` to see if the popups change too.

Minimal fix for this might be toString() in the for loop scope instead.

```cs
for (int timerCtr = 0; timerCtr < timerArray.Length; timerCtr++)
{
    timerArray[timerCtr] = new System.Timers.Timer(timerCtr * 1000 + 1000);

    // string is defined in the for loop instead of Elapsed.
    string toShow = timerCtr.ToString(); 
    string labelName = finalLabelArray[timerCtr].Name.ToString();
    string labelString = labelName;
    int lengthSubstring = labelString.Length - 3;
    int labelNumber = int.Parse(labelString.Substring(3, lengthSubstring));

    timerArray[timerCtr].Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show(toShow);
        // ??? do whatever you want with labelNumber
    };
    timerArray[timerCtr].AutoReset = false;
    timerArray[timerCtr].Start();
}
```